# start an event at a specific timezone on react front-end

Tags: reactjs, datetime, timezone

I'm working on React and I have to do a countdown for an event that start at a precised time at a specific timezone (say 2022/04/20 20:00:00 Paris timezone).

The date is stored in a constant in the front like so :

```js
event:{
start: new Date('2022-04-20T20:00:00'),
end: new Date('2022-04-23T00:00:00')
}
```

Because the date is stored in front, it will correspond to the user local timezone.
I don't know how to do so that the date stays in paris timezone, whatever the user timezone is.
The date has to stay in a Date type because I do calculations in my Timer for the countdown.
I tried to use formatInTimeZone(date, 'Europe/Paris', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz') from the fns-tz package but when I add the "zzz" at the end it returns an invalid date format. 
Also, I noticed that some Dates format are not supported on mobile browsers (the countdown did not display on mobile because of that). 
if I changed the date for '2022-04-20T19:00:00Z' would it be the job ? 
I know that the Z stands for UTC, but in this case is it UTC+0 ?

I'm really not confortable with the timezones and any help would be appreciated.

I tried :

```
import { formatInTimeZone } from "date-fns-tz";

const start = new Date("2022-04-20T20:00:00");
const end = new Date("2022-04-23T00:00:00");

const startdate = formatInTimeZone(start,"Europe/Paris","yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
const enddate = formatInTimeZone(end,"Europe/Paris","yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz");


export const dropDate = {
    start: new Date(startdate),
    end: new Date(enddate),
};
```

It seems to work but not on mobile browser.
The date format is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the date to `'2022-04-20T19:00:00Z'`, it will just factor in the GMT difference. In my case, My GMT is +0530(IST). So, it will just add 5hrs 30 mins to 19:00:00 which results in 00:30:00 of 21st April.
You can make use of [dayjs](https://day.js.org/docs/en/timezone/timezone) library instead.

```
import dayjs from "dayjs";
import utc from "dayjs/plugin/utc";
import relativeTime from "dayjs/plugin/relativeTime";
import timezonePlugin from "dayjs/plugin/timezone";

dayjs.extend(utc);
dayjs.extend(relativeTime);
dayjs.extend(timezonePlugin);

event:{
    start: dayjs("2022-04-20T23:30:00").tz('Europe/Paris'),//This will set the start time to 2022/04/20 20:00:00 Paris timezone
    end: dayjs("2022-04-23T03:30:00").tz('Europe/Paris') // This will set the end time to 2022/04/23 00:00:00 Paris timezone.
}
```

Comment: I edited my post. I think I found a way for the timezone with fns-tz package, but the problem is that it is not working on mobile browsers. The date format is invalid.